# Alternative to AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath for any path?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently I am using the following piece of code to load Textures from image files.

```
Texture my_pic = (Texture) AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(path, typeof(Texture));
```

Unfortunately this method doesn't work if the target path isn't in the `Asset/` folder. I was wondering how I would load an image, given some absolute path of the form

```
/Users/Alan/SomeFolder/SomePic.png
```

(note that I am currently writing a custom Unity editor plugin by extending `EditorWindow` if that matters)

Comment: This post might be helpful https://answers.unity.com/questions/58743/how-to-load-objects-from-a-file-outside-of-unity3d.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that will open a unity file dialog, and load the selected texture into a material of the attached object.

```
string path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Load an image", "", "png");

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) {
  return;
}

// Load the images bytes from file (this is a synchronous call!)
byte[] bytes = null;
try {
    bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
} catch (System.Exception e) {
    Debug.LogError(e.Message);
    return;
}

// Load the bytes into a Unity Texture2D
Texture2D _tex = new Texture2D(2,2);
_tex.LoadImage(bytes);

// Apply this texture to the object
Renderer r = (target as Component).gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
if (r != null) {
    r.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", _tex);
}
```

The last part, just for demonstration, will work only on a script derived from `Editor` because it uses `target` to find the attached renderer. It's up to you to decide what to do with the texture in your `EditorWindow` script.

Also, remember to explicitly call `DestroyImmediate` on your texture when you no longer need it, as you may end up with a memory leak in your editor code.

Comment: Whats up with the seemingly arbitrary dimensions of `new Texture2D(2,2)`

Comment: The Texture2D constructor requires dimensions, so 2x2 is pretty arbitrary. But LoadImage will automatically change the dimensions of the Texture based on the passed data.

Answer (score 3):

## `AssetDatabase` is an Editor-only class.

Furthermore, it can only read assets in the /Assets directory (you know, the ones that are known to the asset database).

If you want to read any file on the file system, you need to use the [System.IO classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UnityWebRequestTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.html)

```cs
var www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("file:///Users/Alan/SomeFolder/SomePic.png");
www.SendWebRequest();
while(!www.isDone)
    continue;
var texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this require to be running in a Coroutine (IEnumerator) which gets a bit tricky in Editor scripting since it has to run outside of the PlayMode (so without `Update`). I'm not sure if they work in `EditorWindow` but you might have to add it to the [`EditorWindow.Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.Update.html)

Comment: UnityWebRequest doesn't require a coroutine (even in play mode).

Comment: well but than the `while(!www.isDone)` will be blocking the entire UnityEditor until it is done ;)

Comment: Yes, you can add `DisplayProgressBar` or  `EditorWindow.Update` that you mentioned to make it better.  But since OP want an alternative, I think `LoadAssetAtPath` is also a blocking method and read data from a HD won't take much time.